# Why does Cocoa binding use both KVC and KVO and not just KVC?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, kvc

As a newbie to Cocoa and Objective-C I have a rudimentary understanding of KVC and KVO.  However with respect to Cocoa Bindings (as covered in the Apple document titled "Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics" see figures 8-10) I'm unclear why they are depicting using both KVC and KVO, when it seems that KVO would be sufficient.  KVO's ObserveValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context can provide the old and new values so why is KVC mechanisms needed?  Note, I see how KVO decouples objects, but so does KVC.

The example Apple gives (figures 8-10) depicts a Window containing a slider and a text input control to visually represent and allow user interaction for setting&viewing "temperature",  a Controller object, and a Model Object with a temperature property.  So put another way my question is why not just have a bi-directional KVO relationships between the 2 controls and the controller (each registers with the other as an observer), and bi-directional KVO relationships between the Model Object and the Controller?  Why is KVC needed?

Comment: KVC is the foundation of KVO; from the documentation: "In order to be considered KVO-compliant for a specific property, a class must ... be key-value coding compliant for the property".

Comment: one detects changes, the other allows them to propogate... not really an answerable in any helpful way...

Comment: To titaniumde and Grady:  KVO uses the change dictionary, and optional context, to tell the observer object what the new property values are.  Therefore it doesn't seem to be a requirement for KVC (at least per the bindings example Apple provides).  In other words, per the referenced example, the Controller's properties only change when the "temperature" property of the model or temperature property of the View's temperature slider or temperature textfield change.  Again since the View and the Model are also observers of the Controller's temperature property, the propagation happens via KVO.

Comment: For example, user changes temperature slider.  Controller is a observer of slider's property so it is notified and changes its temperature property.  Model is an observer of the controller's temperature property so it get's notified, and changes its temperature property.  Hence the needed propagation has occurred, and it can likewise occur in the opposite direction (model to Controller to Slider and TextField).  There does not seem to be any need for KVO.  What am I missing?

Comment: You seem to alternate at random in your question and comments between KVC and KVO; "the propagation happens via KVO" ... "There does not seem to be any need for KVO"... It's hard to answer your question when you seem to use the two acronyms interchangeably.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  It should read "There does not seem to be any need for KVC"  I.e. KVO provides the addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:, and observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context methods which seem to to be sufficient for model -> controller -> view control(s) AND view control(s) -> controller -> model, propagation of value(s) in response to a change of a property value, without the need for KVC.

Comment: Re-edit:Sorry, that was a typo.  It should read "There does not seem to be any need for KVC"  I.e. KVO provides the addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:, and observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context methods which seem to to be sufficient for model -> controller -> view control(s) AND view control(s) -> controller -> model, propagation of "changed" property value(s), without the need for KVC.

Answer (score 2):

The long-winded docs are confusing you.

All this does is about code-reusability.

(1) Provide a standard way to declare and manage properties.
(you can do it manually the old way with ivars and setters and getters, but property synthesis gives it to you for free)

You cannot Observe the Key Value Pairs reliably unless they follow a convention.
The convention is KVC. Following that is being KVC compliant.

(2) Provide a highly reusable and generic way for objects to receive notifications about changes to a property in another object. This is KVO. 
KVO is the ability to generically code notifications based on changes in properties that are KVC compliant first.

(3) Bindings & Core Data. Both technologies are built on KVC and KVO to make this all work in as generic a way as possible.

It is also quite similar conceptually to ORMs like Active Record and Ruby on Rails.
The magic starts with KVC.
KVC enables a simple KVO mechanism.
KVO + KVC make Bindings and Core Data possible and easy.
They also provide a lot of syntactic sugar and wacky conveniences.
You can treat the interface to KVC compliant objects as a dictionary or an array.
Then all the patterns fall into place.

You *can* still have other bi-drectional observer patterns. 
Delegation (setting eachother as or sharing a delegate) and Notification (via NSNotification), or even simply messaging other objects (likely bad tight coupling if this is your pattern everywhere, leading to these other patterns being created)
These are not wrong, but have some trade-offs.

Notifications can be spaghetti code at times. Like all callbacks, you end up with something like goto sometimes. However, it isn't necessarily as tightly coupled to a specific property of a specific object like KVO. It is just waiting for a potentially very general notification that could contain a lot of different things. However, by its nature, Notifications tend to be more use-case specific, and easy to apply to custom scenarios.

KVO as-a-specific-technology is built on KVC conventions, and does not work without them.
It makes some very basic, common boiler-plate code & tight coupling easier to create.

Answer (score 1):

A few have tried in the comments, he's my go:

KVO is essentially built on top of KVC - when a KVC compliant property is changed if there is an observer then the KVO machinery kicks in, constructs the info dictionary as needed, and sends the message to the observer(s).

If they question is why was it done this way and why not another then that is a different question. KVO needs to plug into something - you can't just observe changes to a variable (memory location) in a simple way[*]. A property, having a setter & getter, is a place things such as KVO can hook in. And properties follow the KVC pattern and there is already machinery to support that... But that doesn't mean KVO *has to* depend on KVC, other implementations strategies are undoubtedly possible.

HTH at little.

[*] entering the debugging mode and deploying watchpoints is not "simple" in this context!